# Filter Text from sidebar widget?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, filters

Hey guys,
I'm using a calendar plugin that provides a sidebar widget to show current calendar dates.

However this widget always shows N/A if I don't set a category for a specific event. Any idea how I could add a filter to that widget and match N/A and remove it?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method "widget" look for the line that sets the category then add either:

```
$cat = empty($instance['cat']) ? 'N/A' : $instance['cat'];
```

(where you replace N/A with something you like) or... better... add a filter instead like this:

```
$cat = apply_filters( 'widget_my_cat', empty($instance['cat']) ? 'N/A' : $instance['cat'], $instance, $this->id_base);
```

And then hook into 'widget_my_cat' to set it to something else if the value is 'N/A'